# How to extract image url from a string?

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to extract image url from inside of a string. I am using Pattern and Matcher. I am using a regular expression to match the same. Whenever I am trying to debug the code, both, matcher.matches() and matcher.find() result into false. 
I am attaching the image url and regular expression as well as my code.

```
Pattern pattern_name;
Matcher matcher_name;

String regex = "(http(s?):/)(/[^/]+)+\" + \"\\.(?:jpg|gif|png)";
String url = "http://www.medivision360.com/pharma/pages/articleImg/thumbnail/thumb3756d839adc5da3.jpg";

pattern_name = Pattern.compile(regex);
matcher_name = pattern_name.matcher(url);

matcher_name.matches();
matcher_name.find();
```

Comment: Did you included the library files ?

Comment: sorry.. but which library files? I didn't get you?

Comment: I am afraid you have a typo. You need `(http(s?):/)(/[^/]+)+\\.(?:jpg|gif|png)` or even `https?:/(/[^/]+)+\\.(?:jpg|gif|png)`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN7cQ2/1)

Comment: okay wiktor! Let me check it :)

Comment: that `+\" + \"` looks wrong

Comment: See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/Z4QNrc). Note that `matches` requires a full string match, while `find` will find a partial match, a match inside a larger string.

Comment: @VinayKelkar: [Pattern and Matcher Class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some issue with the regex, the `\" + \"` should come from some code you mistook for a regex. That subpattern requires a quote, one or more spaces, then a space, and another double quote to appear right before the extension. It matches something like [`http://www.medivision360.com/pharma/pages/articleImg/thumbnail/thumb3756d839adc5da3"  ".jpg`](https://regex101.com/r/cC2eE4/1).

Also, there are two redundant capture groups at the beginning, you do not need to use them.

Use

```
String regex = "https?:/(?:/[^/]+)+\\.(?:jpg|gif|png)";
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN7cQ2/1)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/Z4QNrc):

```
String rx = "https?:/(?:/[^/]+)+\\.(?:jpg|gif|png)";
String url = "http://www.medivision360.com/pharma/pages/articleImg/thumbnail/thumb3756d839adc5da3.jpg";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(url);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Note that `Matcher#matches()` requires a full string match, while `Matcher#find()` will find a partial match, a match inside a larger string.

Answer (score 0):

You've escaped the double quotes in the string catenation
so the regex engine sees this `(http(s?):/)(/[^/]+)+" + "\.(?:jpg|gif|png)`
after c++ parses the string.

You can un-escape it `"(http(s?):/)(/[^/]+)+" + "\\.(?:jpg|gif|png)"`
or just join them together `"(http(s?):/)(/[^/]+)+\\.(?:jpg|gif|png)"`

Answer (score 0):

If the expression is always at the end, I would suggest:

```
([^/?]+)(?=/?(?:$|\?))
```

Comment: if the expression is always at the end...? I didn't get you mate? sorry...?

Comment: @VinayKelkar, I apologize for not being clearer. If the text to be extracted is always at the end of the String (as in your example that ends with `/thumb3756d839adc5da3.jpg'), then this regular expression will extract it. So if the URL always ends with the filename, this regex will pull it without the attempt to limit by a particular extension.